# Is a high WaitDrawable score a bad thing? What causes it?

Tags: macos, scenekit

I have a SceneKit scene with not a great deal going on in it at the moment. Initially the reported statistics are all very low (0.2ms for rendering, everything else zero). But, if I resize the view just a little, the WaitDrawable figure is highly likely (but not guaranteed) to go up significantly, usually to just under 8ms or just under 16ms. Subsequent resizes very rarely cause it to drop a little. I have only once seen it recover to zero.

`WaitDrawable` does not return any matches on developer.apple.com, and barely any on the wider internet.

I thought using a SpriteKit scene as an overlay (via `scnView.overlaySKScene = ...`) might be the culprit and if somehow SpriteKit was late (or dropped a frame entirely?) then SceneKit would end up waiting for frame N+1, but removing all trace of the overlay had no effect on the behaviour.

I also considered whether being an `NSWindowDelegate` and reacting to `windowDidResize` could be the cause, so removed that code - no change.

All that remains is code to load the scene and start an `SCNAction.repeatForever` and still the high WaitDrawable appears on resize. It's not related to view size - a clean launch followed by several reductions in window size just caused it to happen too.

Instruments readout for the last good frame and first bad frame shows WaitDrawable increase by 1000x:

[image: Good frame followed by bad frame]

The trace for the corresponding moment in time, which I'm currently not able to decipher, but even to my untrained eye, it does look odd:

[image: Instruments trace of transition from good to bad]

It doesn't actually seem to hurt frame rate, but at 16ms it's right on the verge. [Apple's own Fox2 demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/scenekit-2017/Introduction/Intro.html) exhibits the same high WaitDrawable.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: @RossKimes No. I did submit a radar on the Fox2 demo, but it hasn't received any attention. I'm still not even sure whether it's a real problem. I suppose it could be an instruments error rather than an actual performance problem - it always seems to fill  the time available for a frame, without actually dropping frames. I'm not sure how you'd tell the difference.